# How to install mongo db on Macbook (not M1)

Tags: mongodb

I just typed brew install mongo and it it giving me this as output .

My question is what to do now , which I have to install mongo-c-driver , mongo-cxx-driver   ,   mongo-orchestration ,  mongoose

Thank you

```
shouryasharma@Shouryas-MacBook-Air ~ % brew install mongo
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 3 casks.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
mongo-c-driver        mongo-cxx-driver      mongo-orchestration   mongoose
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install mongo-c-driver
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "mongo".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
shouryasharma@Shouryas-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

Before execute command "brew install" just execute the command,

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Also you can find all the steps on official site of mongodb ,

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/